# How to condtionally format a table with several conditions?

Tags: excel

I have a table with different dates. I need 3 conditions to be fullfilled.

- In red : Dates that already passed today (I tried less than =now() and this works)
- In yellow : Dates should get highlighted in yellow when we are 2 weeks before their cell value.
- In green : all the rest.

I just can't wrap my head around it... thanks for the help guys.

```
Monitoring 1    Monitoring 2    Monitoring 3    Monitoring 4    Monitoring 5 Monitoring 6
2019-05-31      2019-11-30      2020-05-31      2020-11-30      2021-05-31  2021-10-31
2019-04-30      2019-10-31      2020-04-30      2020-10-31      2021-04-30  2021-09-30
2019-04-30      2019-10-31      2020-04-30      2020-10-31      2021-04-30  2021-09-30
2019-04-30      2019-10-31      2020-04-30      2020-10-31      2021-04-30  2021-09-30
2019-03-31      2019-09-30      2020-03-31      2020-09-30      2021-03-31  2021-08-31
2019-03-31      2019-09-30      2020-03-31      2020-09-30  2021-03-31  2021-08-31
```

Comment: Highlight them all green then two rules.  You already have the red, for yellow: `=A1<TodaY()+14`

Comment: @ScottCraner Where do i put this formula?

Comment: use Conditional formatting

Comment: @ScottCraner It overwrites what is already in red...

Comment: put them in the correct order and select stop after true.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Excel sees them **as** dates, which is not a given, even if they appear to be formatted as such, you almost have the rule formulas in hand. It's important, however, that you do two things.

Define them in the following order.

1. Yellow
2. Red
3. Green

Strictly speaking, you need only two rules, because you can and should apply green as your default cell color.

The other thing that you must do on at least the Yellow rule is to tell Excel to stop processing when the condition of this rule is met.

If you've already defined the rules, you can use the up and down controls in the rules editor to put them in the correct order.

Finally, I would apply the rule to cell A2, then copy the formatting, via Paste Special, into the rest of the worksheet.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i'm not sure where and what formula should I use..

Comment: The Red formula for cell B2 would be something like =b2<now() while the Yello formula would be something like =b4<b2-14, since two weeks is 14 days, and the Date part of an Excel Date/Time entry is a whole number of days since 1 January 1901.